# HTML 5 Mobile Safari Video is not playing unless accessed directly

Tags: html, jquery-mobile, safari, mobile-safari, html5-video

I am using jquery mobile and video tag to display videos. 
My video plays fine on all 'desktop' browsers, but when play when I use the following code in mobile safari (iPhone) it shows only black rectangle without any controls.

I used video used commonly in html5 examples. (from http://www.bigbuckbunny.org) so it shouldn't be encoding issue.

When I access video directly by typing its url http://myurlofvideo.mp4 it plays correctly in mobile Safari.

What's causing the problem?

Thank you in advance!

```
<video width="75%"  id="video1" controls="true"  autoplay="true">
<source src="videos/mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
<source src="videos/mov_bbb.webm" type="video/webm">
Your browser does not support the video tag. 
</video>
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried the sample below in iphone simulator and it is working ,check it out .

```
<video width="320" height="240" controls>
   <source src="http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4" type="video/mp4">  
   Your browser does not support the video tag.
   </video>
```

it shows preview image of the video,when you click on it plays in fullscreen.

Comment: Nope. it doesn't. The problem is jquerymobile.